# generic type variable constraints in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am looking for the equivalent of the following c# syntax for typescript

```
public abstract class PBaseHierarchical<T> : PBase where T : PBaseHierarchical<T>
    {
...
}
```

I only find the constraint "extends" which would be the following in typescript:

```
export abstract class PBaseHierarchical<T extends PBaseHierarchical<T>> extends PBase {
...
}
```

But from my understanding "extends" says that T should inherit from PBaseHierarchical. What I want is that T is of type PBaseHierarchical.

Thanks a lot for any help !

Comment: `extends` in type constraint is actually covers both: _is of type PBaseHierarchical or "extends" PBaseHierarchical_. Pretty much the same as `where T : PBaseHierarchical` in c#

Comment: Hi Alekey - thanks for your feedback ! If you post your answer I could mark it as a such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extends` in type constraint is actually covers both:

> T is of type PBaseHierarchical **or** T "extends" PBaseHierarchical

Pretty much the same as where T : PBaseHierarchical in C#.

Also pay attention that types are compared structurally in Typescript.